# How to make android widgets using python?

Tags: python, android-widget, android, sl4a

Is there any way to make widgets with Python on Android?

I mean, that I know only `Python`, `HTML`, `DOM`, `JS`, maybe `jQuery` and **nothing more** (not `C`, `Java` or something).

Maybe it's simple?

I honestly searched `stackoverflow` but search returned no answers :(

Help me, please. Give me a hope.

Comment: And javascript isn't enough? You can use w3c widgets then I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wrote a google app engine app in python to collect and display the data, and then used an app called "meta widget" that allows you to turn a website's content into a widget. The app pulls the content from my GAE website and shows it in a widget on the android homescreen.

You might be able to do something completely local if you can make something to serve HTTP requests in sl4a python, then have meta widget go to a local http address.

Comment: Hmm, I think that's the best solution at this time. Thank you! Also I've found that Py4A now supports generic ui layouts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this could be done.

I've done a quick search in [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference) documentation and there is no API to register broadcast receiver. And [Android widgets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) are just a bunch of Views and code in BroadcastReceiver.

And as far as I know, SL4A is the only way to use Python on Android with UI interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this links:

- http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/
- http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html

Remember that there is a Python implementation on the JVM called Jython.

Edit: 
In terms of Android development i should say [Jythonroid](http://code.google.com/p/jythonroid/).

Comment: As I understand Jython works by compiling Python source to JVM byte-code on the fly. But Android does not have JVM, it has different VM implementation called Dalvik (http://www.dalvikvm.com/). And Dalvik is not byte-code compatible with JVM, so this generated code could not be executed.

Comment: You are right. There are some things that the Dalvik cant do, or cant do equally. But just like you say Jython is converted to Java bytecodes, and this can be then converted to Dalvik. See this [link](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android_FAQ#Q:_Is_Python_available_for_Android.3F)

Comment: okay, I understand. But how it can looks like in practice? Maybe, simple widget's code example? please..

Answer (score 0):

[Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) perhaps?  Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but it would allow you to at least write some of your code in Python (and compile to JavaScript).

Comment: I can use JS to make desktop widgets on Android?!

Comment: @Крайст - sorry, missed the part about wanting to do desktop widgets; I thought you were looking for a way to get a Python-based app going.

Comment: ammm... I want to know, how can I make/write home screen widgets for android. In Python or maybe in js (Opera makes this possible, as I know)